# Table row highlight on hover using JQuery with IE- all versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a table in jsp page which have many rows and columns, I want to keep visitors oriented on my page, when they move their mouse on the row or column it should be highlighted with the diffrent background color.
My `**hover funtionality**` code is working fine with other browsers like crome,firefox not with the `IE` and i need to keep `content="IE-5"`

Here is my code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#reportDashBoardTable tr').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
  );
});

 <style type="text/css">
    .hover { background-color:#B0C4DE; }
 </<style>
```

How i can do it for IE-all versions?

Thanks in advance!

Anand

Comment: this can be simply make possible with CSS then why we need to use javascript?

Comment: "*[I] need to keep `content="IE-5"`*" - you have my heartfelt sympathy.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using CSS? It should be supported in almost every IE version (except everything under 3)

```
#reportDashBoardTable :hover { background-color:#B0C4DE; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working with IE-5,i need this functionality only with Document Mode:IE5-quicks.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily use css for achieve this

```
<style type="text/css">
    table tr:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Does that work with 'all versions' of IE? I thought IE6 had some issues with only applying/allowing `:hover` on `<a>` elements?

Comment: i didn't check it with IE6.

Comment: it will sure support by IE7 and above. see the link for more info http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/highlight-table-row.php

Comment: If only the requirement was IE 7 and above, as it's "all versions" I'm not convinced that this could be considered a solution as the question is written.Though, admittedly, I wouldn't bother supporting even IE7 any more.

Comment: yes, #David Thomas i am agreed with you. if i go with the #Frebin solution it is working with the all browser but not with the IE-5. I need this functionality with IE-5 where Document Mode :IE5-quicks. with differnet IE Document Mode IE-7 it is working but my other css will get affected so i have to go with only IE5 Document Mode.